# How to save css style of element after refreshing the page in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example, after clicking on **Hide** button some items disappear

```
function hideItem() {
            targList = document.getElementsByClassName("completed");
            document.getElementsByClassName("completed")
            if (targList) {
                for (var x = 0; x < targList.length; x++) {
                    targList[x].setAttribute('style', 'display: none !important');
                }
            }
            localStorage.setItem("autosave", targList);
        }
```

But after refreshing the page style of items do not save. How to preserve this style of element after reloading web page?

Comment: Better to set style is: `targList[x].style.display='none';`

Comment: where to your localStorage.getItem("autosave") section in code? You must do after document reloaded.

Comment: @ITgoldman I know but without !important it does not work

Comment: @TayfunYuksel Where I should write it, before the function?

Comment: the best is to toggle class name with style. You can "save it on refresh" only if html is got generated with js, otherwise you'll have to wait while html got loaded and then run js function that will toggle class on target element, in this case there might be a flickering: element got shown on html load and was hidden after function runs

Comment: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   targList =  localStorage.getItem("autosave"); for (var x = 0; x < targList.length; x++) {  targList[x].setAttribute('style', 'display: none !important');
                }
   });

Comment: Everything in local storage is saved as a string. When you save html elements in local storage, they're stored like this: `'[object HTMLDivElement]'`. Really, this makes sense too, right? What sense does it make to store a dom node on a page that no longer exists? What would you be storing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store DOM into localStorage. You'd have to save identifying code for each element. For example, `id`.

Then do the opposite after loading the page.

```js
function hideItem() {
  var targList = document.getElementsByClassName("completed");
  var hidden_ids = []
  for (var x = 0; x < targList.length; x++) {
    targList[x].setAttribute('style', 'display: none !important');
    hidden_ids.push(targList[x].id)
  }
  localStorage.setItem("autosave", JSON.stringify(hidden_ids));
}

function loadItem() {
  var hidden_ids = Json.parse(localStorage.getItem("autosave") || '[]');
  for (var x = 0; x < hidden_ids.length; x++) {
    document.getElementById(hidden_ids[x]).setAttribute('style', 'display: none !important');
  }
}
hideItem();
```

```html
<div id="elem1" class="completed">hello</div>
<div id="elem2" class="not-completed">hello</div>
```

Comment: Why error occurs in loadItem() function? Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')

Comment: Also I call hideItem() onclick to the button, should I also add onclick="hideItem(); loadItem();"

Comment: You call `loadItem` onload of page. You call `hideItem` when button click. Did you set unique id's for the elements? What does the localStorage look like? (see in devtools -> Application )

Comment: Thank you, it works. However, I also have showItem() function. How I can connect them? Should I write another loadItem() function or what?

Comment: Well it depends what you want each of the functions to do. By the way, the function names are singular whereas there are many items.

Comment: I described more detailed here, can you check please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72919854/how-to-keep-css-style-of-element-after-reloading-the-web-page-in-js